# Can't get CLion to actually use GCC compiler instead of Clang?

Tags: c++, gcc, cmake, clion

I've tried following all the help to change my compiler to use GCC instead of Clang (on macOS) as I would like to try to use `__gnu_pbds::priority_queue` instead of the STL version, and it still appears that CMake uses Clang. I've made a toolchain that looks like this:

[image]

and set it to be used in the CMake profile.

[image]

However, it appears CMake skips actually using the compiler - here is the CMake output:

```
/Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/mac/bin/cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/usr/bin/gcc -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/usr/bin/g++ -G "CodeBlocks - Unix Makefiles" -S /Users/steve/CLionProjects/TestModernTimeStretch -B /Users/steve/CLionProjects/TestModernTimeStretch/cmake-build-release-gcc
-- The C compiler identification is AppleClang 13.1.6.13160021
-- The CXX compiler identification is AppleClang 13.1.6.13160021
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/g++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Looking for stdbool.h
-- Looking for stdbool.h - found
-- Looking for unistd.h
-- Looking for unistd.h - found
-- Checking processor clipping capabilities...
-- Performing Test CPU_CLIPS_POSITIVE
-- Performing Test CPU_CLIPS_POSITIVE - Failed
-- Performing Test CPU_CLIPS_NEGATIVE
-- Performing Test CPU_CLIPS_NEGATIVE - Failed
-- Checking processor clipping capabilities... none
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /Users/steve/CLionProjects/TestModernTimeStretch/cmake-build-release-gcc
```

Comment: Could you please also show GCC being selected for the cmake profile?

Comment: Your `Build, Execution, Deployment -> Cmake` is set correctly as well, yes? Also, if you have multiple build configurations for different compilers and you go into the Cmake console in Clion, it keeps all the different build configurations open there in different tabs. Are you sure you are viewing the correct one?

Comment: The target directory of the configuration didn't contain any existing configuration of a cmake project I assume?

Comment: @JaneDoe Yes, I see the tabs and I'm on Release-GCC one, also just added picture of my CMake profile

Comment: @PhilMasteG Added pic of CMake profile

Comment: It appears you are configured for `/usr/bin/g++` (which is Apple's soft-link *alias* to Clang++), rather than `/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/11.3.0_1/bin/g++-11`.  Have you installed GCC?

Comment: @Eljay Ah that's it, thanks! I guess the /usr/bin one is the Apple installed one that is not GNU

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are configured for `/usr/bin/g++` (which is Apple's soft-link alias to Clang++), rather than `/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/11.3.0_1/bin/g++-11`

---

*(nb. this was @Eljay's comment to the OP's question, which was the correct answer - posting it here as the answer so it can be marked as such)*